# JFrame window doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm learning basic Java GUI programming from a tutorial, and this code is supposed to generate a window with a title, some text, and some tooltip text. It doesn't generate anything. Can anyone tell me why it isn't working?

```
//In a class called apples:

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class apples extends JFrame {

    private JLabel item1;

    public apples() {
        super("Title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        item1 = new JLabel("This is some displayed text");
        item1.setToolTipText("This is some tooltip text.");
        add(item1);
    }

}
```

```
//In the main class class1:
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class class1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        apples green = new apples();
        green.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: try `green.setVisible(true)`. And please make your classes start with uppercase letter.

Comment: Where should I type that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try like below?

```
class Class1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        apples green = new apples();
        green.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        green.setSize(1000, 500); // set window's size.
        green.pack(); // packs the components closely together.
        green.setVisible(true); // makes the window visible.
    }
}
```

Comment: `green.setVisible(true); // should be last, immediately after pack()`

Comment: `immediately after pack()`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have setVisible(true) on last time.